# Integrate NodeJS server into Cloudflare worker

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I need help integrating a NodeJS server that handles authentication into my workers index.js file. I am trying to respond to specific HTTP requests in the following code snippet:

```
catch (e) {
    if (!DEBUG) {
      try {
        // Add code here
      }
    }
}
```

Here is an example HTTP request that needs to be added to index.js:
`app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {//Logic}`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You have to `return` a Response object